# Как красиво отформатировать python-скрипт, который вызывается в bash скрипте?

Tags: python, bash

У меня есть такой код:

```
if [[ $ENABLE_DIND == 1 ]]; then

        python3 <<EOF
import pathlib
import subprocess
import time

path = pathlib.Path('/var/run/docker.sock')
while not path.exists():
  time.sleep(0.01)
try:
  subprocess.call(['chmod', '0666', '/var/run/docker.sock'])
except Exception as e:
  print(e)
EOF

fi;
```

Мне не нравится как отформатирована часть, которая вызывает Python-код. Но при этом любые попытки навести красоту, приводят к тому, что bash ругается на синтаксис.

Comment: можно использовать `<<-`, если для отступа в heredoc использовать табы, а для питоновского кода — пробелы... а вообще в этом случае я бы не мешал скрипты и сделал бы всё на баше...

Comment: а как это сделать на баше? я этот язык почти не знаю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно просто оставить и смирится. Форматирование встроенных документов с начала строки — вполне привычная вещь для bash'а.

Можно также использовать `<<-` и табами для отбивки отступов:

```bsh
if [[ $ENABLE_DIND == 1 ]]; then
    python3 <<-EOF
        import pathlib
        import subprocess
        import time

        path = pathlib.Path('/var/run/docker.sock')
        while not path.exists():
          time.sleep(0.01)
        try:
          subprocess.call(['chmod', '0666', '/var/run/docker.sock'])
        except Exception as e:
          print(e)
        EOF
fi
```

Внимание: здесь отступы встроенного документа должны быть отбиты именно символами табуляции (`\t`), а код питона — пробелами. Данное различие на сайте может отображаться некорректно.

---

Но в данном случае всё это намного проще будет сделать сразу на `bash`'е:

```
if [[ $ENABLE_DIND == 1 ]]; then

  while [ ! -e /var/run/docker.sock ]; do
    sleep 0.01
  done

  chmod 0666 /var/run/docker.sock
fi
```

Также вместо тупого ожидания файла можно было бы сделать это с помощью чего-то более технологичного вроде `inotify` (если дело на linux), но в данном случае это не даст особых преимуществ...

Ещё более правильным решением было бы найти, где почесать ту штуку, которая создаёт этот файл, чтобы она делала это сразу с нужными правами или как-то другим способом настроить права, но это уже будет совсем другая история...

Comment: Спасибо. Если использовать python либу asyncio - это даст преимущество по сравнению с простым bash while?

Comment: Я когда Ваш код башевский применил, то получил ошибку: chmod: changing permissions of '/var/run/docker.sock': Operation not permitted

Comment: @ViktorAndriichuk, про `asyncio`: почти наверняка — нет... то что выше написано на bash делает в точности тоже самое, что и код на питоне... если выдаёт ошибку, то проблема где-то ещё... в частности, см. права на файл и пользователя от которого запускаешь скрипт...

Comment: Если я делаю так: while [ ! -e /var/run/docker.sock ], то он сразу идет на chmod 0666, а файла еще нет и оно падает, а если while [ ! -f /var/run/docker.sock ], то выпадает в бесконечный цикл )

Comment: @ViktorAndriichuk, второе впадает в бесконечный цикл потому что это, скорей всего, это сокет, а не обычный файл... почему первое не работает — сказать отсюда сложно, но могу предположить, что там остаётся какой-то старый файл, который успевает удалится в промежутке между проверкой и `chmod`'ом... в таком слёчае это должно "лечится" добавлением дополкительной задержки перед первой проверкой...

Comment: Хм, спасибо. Буду думать над Вашим комментариям. Спасибо, что просветили, что сокет и обычный файл по разному идентифицируются.